# Is there a way to sum data grouping by date with a time period?

Tags: r

I have data which associates a time period (actually a start date and end date) and a continuous value.
I'd like to find a way to sum the values of my third variable for each day during the time period.

For example with this table :

```
       START        END NUMBER
1  2020-03-16 2020-05-31      5
2  2020-03-16 2020-06-30      7
3  2020-03-17 2020-08-31      1
```

Have a new table with :

```
DAY        SUM
2020-03-16    12
2020-03-17    13
2020-03-18    13
...
2020-05-31    13
2020-06-01    8
...
```

And so on. Is there a way to do that? Maybe with the help of lubridate?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Base R** Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end lapply over erach row expanding the date range into a sequence of dates using `seq`.  This gives a list with one component per input row and we rbind those together giving `long`.  Then aggregate `long` by `Date`.  No packages are used.

```
expand <- function(i, data) with(data[i, ], 
  data.frame(Date = seq(START, END, "day"), NUMBER)
)

long <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(DF), expand, data = DF))
result <- aggregate(NUMBER ~ Date, long, sum)

head(result)
```

giving:

```
        Date NUMBER
1 2020-03-16     12
2 2020-03-17     13
3 2020-03-18     13
4 2020-03-19     13
5 2020-03-20     13
6 2020-03-21     13
```

**2) dplyr**  Expand each row in the `rowwise` code and then sum `NUMBER` over `Date` in the `group_by` code.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  rowwise %>%
  do(data.frame(Date = seq(.$START, .$END, "day"), NUMBER = .$NUMBER)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(NUMBER = sum(NUMBER)) %>%
  ungroup
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "       START        END NUMBER
1  2020-03-16 2020-05-31      5
2  2020-03-16 2020-06-30      7
3  2020-03-17 2020-08-31      1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
DF[1:2] <- lapply(DF[1:2], as.Date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, c('START', 'END') := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.Date(as.character(x))), .SDcols = 1:2][
  , .(DAY = seq(START, END, by = 'day'), NUMBER = NUMBER), by = 1:nrow(df)][
    , .(SUM = sum(NUMBER)), by = DAY]
```

Output:

```
            DAY SUM
  1: 2020-03-16  12
  2: 2020-03-17  13
  3: 2020-03-18  13
  4: 2020-03-19  13
  5: 2020-03-20  13
 ---               
165: 2020-08-27   1
166: 2020-08-28   1
167: 2020-08-29   1
168: 2020-08-30   1
169: 2020-08-31   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option using non-equi join:

```
ans <- DT[.(DATE=seq(min(START), max(END), by="1 day")), on=.(START<=DATE, END>=DATE), 
    by=.EACHI, .(SUM=sum(NUMBER))][, (1L) := NULL][]
setnames(ans, "END", "DAY")[]
```

output:

```
            DAY SUM
  1: 2020-03-16  12
  2: 2020-03-17  13
  3: 2020-03-18  13
  4: 2020-03-19  13
  5: 2020-03-20  13
 ---               
165: 2020-08-27   1
166: 2020-08-28   1
167: 2020-08-29   1
168: 2020-08-30   1
169: 2020-08-31   1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("START        END NUMBER
2020-03-16 2020-05-31      5
2020-03-16 2020-06-30      7
2020-03-17 2020-08-31      1")
cols <- c("START", "END")
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), .SDcols=cols]
```